# Change in where clause only for 100's of different report, merge it into only one

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssrs-2012

I have to create and subscribe several SSRS reports based on one single change in the same SQL query. 
e.g

`SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE value IN (123,456,789)`

Report based on the above query should go to the emailaddress1@test.com
Similarly

`SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE value IN (111,222,333) - emailaddress2@test.com
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE value IN (444,555,666) - emailaddress3@test.com
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE value IN (777,888,999) - emailaddress4@test.com`

the change is only in value for every report, and i have to send every report to different email address.

Is there any way to do this other than creating 100's of separate reports ?

Comment: Can you add a separate table where you link "value" to "mail address"?

Comment: @HansKesting no separate table is not an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can parameterize the report so that you only have one report, and create a separate subscription with the parameters values for each email address.